# how to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' error in google translator

Tags: python, google-translation-api

i am building a google translator with tkinter and googletrans, and everything looks good and works well until i added the last part of it that handles what happens when you press the translator button, that is, this function:

```
def translate_now():
    text_ = text1.get(1.0, END)
    t1 = Translator()
    trans_text = t1.translate(text_, src=combo1.get(), dest=combo2.get())
    trans_text = trans_text.text

    text2.delete(1.0, END)
    text2.insert(END, trans_text)
```

it then gives me this error when i run it:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\Downloads\translator\main.py", line 24, in translate_now
    trans_text = t1.translate(text_, src=combo1.get(), dest=combo2.get())
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\Downloads\translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\Downloads\translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\Downloads\translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\FSTC\Downloads\translator\venv\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

below is my full source code for more clarity:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

root = Tk()
root.title("Google Translator")
root.geometry("1080x400")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(background="white")


def label_change():
    c = combo1.get()
    c1 = combo2.get()
    label1.configure(text=c)
    label2.configure(text=c1)
    root.after(1000, label_change)


def translate_now():
    text_ = text1.get(1.0, END)
    t1 = Translator()
    trans_text = t1.translate(text_, src=combo1.get(), dest=combo2.get())
    trans_text = trans_text.text

    text2.delete(1.0, END)
    text2.insert(END, trans_text)


# icon
image_icon = PhotoImage(file="images.png")
root.iconphoto(False, image_icon)

# arrow
arrow_image = PhotoImage(file="arrow.png")
image_label = Label(root, image=arrow_image, width=150)
image_label.place(x=460, y=50)

language = googletrans.LANGUAGES
languageV = list(language.values())
lang1 = language.keys()

# first combobox
combo1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=languageV, font="Roboto 14", state="r")
combo1.place(x=110, y=20)
combo1.set("ENGLISH")

label1 = Label(root, text="ENGLISH", font="segoe 30 bold", bg="white", width=18, bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
label1.place(x=10, y=50)

# second combobox
combo2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=languageV, font="Roboto 14", state="r")
combo2.place(x=730, y=20)
combo2.set("SELECT LANGUAGE")

label2 = Label(root, text="ENGLISH", font="segoe 30 bold", bg="white", width=18, bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
label2.place(x=620, y=50)

# frame 1
f = Frame(root, bg="black", bd=5)
f.place(x=10, y=118, width=440, height=210)

text1 = Text(f, font="Robote 20", bg="white", relief=GROOVE, wrap=WORD)
text1.place(x=0, y=0, width=430, height=200)

scrollbar1 = Scrollbar(f)
scrollbar1.pack(side="right", fill="y")
scrollbar1.configure(command=text1.yview)
text1.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)

# frame 2
f1 = Frame(root, bg="black", bd=5)
f1.place(x=620, y=118, width=440, height=210)

text2 = Text(f1, font="Robote 20", bg="white", relief=GROOVE, wrap=WORD)
text2.place(x=0, y=0, width=430, height=200)

scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(f1)
scrollbar2.pack(side="right", fill="y")
scrollbar2.configure(command=text2.yview)
text2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)

# button to translate
translate = Button(root, text="Translate", font=("Roboto", 15), activebackground="white", cursor="hand2",
                   bd=1, width=10, height=2, bg="black", fg="white", command=translate_now)
translate.place(x=476, y=250)

label_change()

root.mainloop()
```

am suspecting it may be having problems connecting to google translator or something similar. but what could be the problem precisely?

Comment: Try printing `text_`, `combo1.get()`, and `combo2.get()`. Something is wrong with those because when you pass them to `t1.translate`, it raises an error.

Comment: i get valid results when i print them out. what could then be the error

Comment: Try manually inputting them in `print(Translator().translate(...).text)`.

Comment: i do this:  print(Translator().translate("end","arabic","ENGLISH")) and i get this result:    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Therefore the error isn't in `tkinter`, it's in how you are using `.translate(...)`. I have no experience with Google's translate library so read the documentation. The only thing I can point out is that `"arabic"` is lowercase and `"ENGLISH"` is uppercase. I replaced the `tkinter` tag from the question with `google-translate-api`

Comment: Successfully uninstalled idna-3.3
  Running setup.py install for googletrans ... done
Successfully installed chardet-3.0.4 googletrans-4.0.0rc1 h11-0.9.0 h2-3.2.0 hpack-3.0.0 hstspreload-2022.9.1 httpcore-0.9.1 httpx-0.13.3 hyperframe-5.2.0 idna-2.1
0 rfc3986-1.5.0 sniffio-1.3.0
i installed the latest version of googletrans and ran the code again but still gave the same error message

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because you dont have updated version of googletrans,
so use update version of googletrans :
Command to install update version: "pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0"
This will solve your problem.

Comment: OP already stated in the comments that "installed the latest version of googletrans" was performed. Re-suggesting what has already been tried is usually not a helpful response